# Having problem in accessing values from state when traversing an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm trying to traverse an Array and perform some operation. But cann't access the values as i want to.

```
inputObj.map(el => {
    const msg = this.state.validation[el.id].message;
    const msg2 = this.state.validation['name'].message;
})
```

Here, `el.id` can be `name`, `dob` or `address`. When i use `this.state.validation[el.id].message;`, it shows `TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined`. But if i hardcode it like `this.state.validation['name'].message;`, it works fine. when comparing both `el.id` and `'name'`, they have same datatype and same value. So, why having problem when using `el.id` instead of hardcoding it.

NB: i'm using `reactjs`.

**Edit:**

this.state:

```
this.state = {
    super(props);
    this.validator = new FormValidator([
        {
            field: 'name',
            method: 'isEmpty',
            validWhen: false,
            message: 'Name is required'
        },
        ...
    ]);

    orderForm: {
        name: {
             elementType: 'input',
             elementConfig: ''
        },
        ...
    }

    validation: this.validator.setValid() // it will be the updated upon submitting form on submitHandler by calling validate() from FormValidator
}
```

inputObj:

```
   const inputObj= [];
   for(let key in this.state.orderForm){
       inputObj.push({
           id : key,
           config: this.state.orderForm[key]
       });
   }
```

FormValidator

```
import validator from 'validator';

class FormValidator {
    constructor(rules){
        this.rules = rules;
    }

    setValid(){
        const validation = {};
        this.rules.map(rule => (
            validation[rule.field] = {isValid: true, message: ''}
        ));
        return {isValid: true, ...validation};
    }

    validate(form){
        let validation = this.setValid();
        this.rules.forEach( rule => {
            if (validation[rule.field].isValid){
                const field = form[rule.field].toString();
                const args = rule.args || [];
                const validationMethod = typeof rule.method === 'string' ?
                    validator[rule.method] : rule.method;

                if (validationMethod(field, ...args, form) !== rule.validWhen){
                    validation[rule.field] = {isValid: false, message: rule.message};
                    validation.isValid = false;
                }
            }
        });
        return validation;
    }
}

export default FormValidator;
```

Comment: can you show how `this.state.validation` looks like ? and `inputObj` too

Comment: If this works `this.state.validation['name'].message`, `el.id` is not equal to `"name"` try to put a `console.log` to show the value of `el.id` into your `map` loop

Comment: i checked it by console.log and comparing them. i checked their type and also value using if-else and i found them of same type and same value. @R3tep

Comment: Where does your `inputObj` come from? Maybe it's asynchronous code and it's not populated yet when you execute the loop. Do a `console.log(el)` in your loop to check what's inside

Comment: It's not possible. See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) And there are no error into the code provided, so edit with more info if you want help. Like `inputObj` content and the same for `this.state.validation`

Comment: i have added necessary codes. hope it will be clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if `this.state.validation[el.id]` is defined before getting `message` key.

Like that you can't get fatal error.

```
inputObj.map(el => {
  this.state.validation[el.id] && (
    const msg = this.state.validation[el.id].message
  );
})
```